# Internet Explorer 7 css js table column display bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

There is a strange bug which I can't solve.

The bug is reproducable by this simplified example:

css:

```
table.class1 td.subclass1{ display : none }
table.class2 td.subclass2{ display : none }
```

html:

```
<table class="class1">
 <tr>
  <td class="subclass1"> Invisible </td>
  <td class="subclass2"> Visible </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

js ( jQuery)

```
$("table.class1").removeClass("class1").addClass("class2);
```

As you can see Internet Explorer 7 doesn't show the column "Visible":

[image: Bug Demo]

You may take a look at this bug here:

[Fiddle Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Ehtcm/4/)

What do I have to do to switch from one column to another column?

Unfortunately I can't change the HTML but only the CSS and JS.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 seems to have problems with the display:none property. If you do all of the show/hide rendering in javascript it will work as expected.

I've updated the code in jsFiddle with the working solution. (I should've forked it, but I already pressed update, sorry about that)

[jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Yr36F/1/)

Comment: With "problems with the display:none property" I mean when IE7 first renders the table. After the initial rendering, you can fool with the table with Javascript what you want, and it seems to work correctly.

Comment: Is this answer useful for you?

Comment: sry my bad, I tested it hours after reading and forgot to vote and accept. Thx a lot for your help!